# How make data transfer between host and device more faster?

Tags: opencl

I am coding some program and i need to perform some data transfer repeatedly between host and device. I will try to minimize best i can, but is there any faster way to perform this? Here, array copied to the device is changing on each iteration, hence device needs to be updated with the new array values. Any suggestions/pointers/help will be appreciated.

```
for (i = 0; i <= SEVERALCALLS; i++) {

    wrtBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double) * num, NULL, &ret);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clCreateBuffer wrtBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }

    // update cti array

    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, wrtBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(double) * num, cti, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clEnqueueWriteBuffer wrtBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }

    // NDRange Kernel call

    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, readBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(double) * num, newcti, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("clEnqueueReadBuffer readBuffer error: %d. couldn't load\n", ret);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use discrete GPU? What is the IO speed you have right now and what is PCI-E bus speed on your machine?

Comment: yes it is a discrete GPU. I am using GEForce GTX 630 KEPLER http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-630/specifications

Comment: Compare your results against PCI-E bandwidth on different transfer amounts. If you get over 75% of theoretical maximum, usually, it means that transfer speed is OK. If that is not enough, look at the pinned memory technique, which is described in Nvidia OpenCl best practices.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try and share the results..

Comment: You need interleave copy and execution. That can be achieved by having 2 buffers and 2 queues. Such that you are copying the new data while the old is still running.

Comment: Why do you create a new buffer on every iteration of the loop instead of re-using the buffer?  Also, `wrtBuffer` is pinned host memory (not device memory) because you are using `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR`.  You should map this buffer to get a pointer that you can assign to `cti`.  You need a second buffer allocated in device memory that you will write the data in `cti` to using `clEnqueueWriteBuffer`.  This write operation will get the maximum PCIe bus bandwidth.  At the moment I suspect your code is passing `wrtBuffer` to your kernel, forcing the GPU to go over PCIe for every memory access.

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to optimize this:

1. On integrated GPU (like Intel or AMD APU) use "zero copy" buffers so you won't pay for any transfers.
2. On NVIDIA use pinned host memory for the host-side memory source for clEnqueueWriteBuffer or receive buffer for clEnqueueReadBuffer. This will be faster than using normal malloc memory and won't block.
3. Overlap transfer and compute. Use three command queues, one for upload, one for compute, and one for download, and use events to ensure dependencies. See NVIDIA's example: [oclCopyComputeOverlap](https://github.com/sschaetz/nvidia-opencl-examples/blob/master/OpenCL/src/oclCopyComputeOverlap/oclCopyComputeOverlap.cpp) (although it is suboptimal; it can go slightly faster than they say it can).